# What does domain trust attribute 0x800000 mean?

Tags: active-directory

A domain in an AD Forest has a trustAttributes value set to 0x800000. [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223779%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)  lists this as reserved, but it appears that Microsoft themselves use it for something. My question is: What does domain trust attribute 0x800000 mean?

Comment: Well this could be even from trust domain wizard, that the trust is either established or not

Comment: I've only ever seen that in the context of a Windows 2000 domain, and it's even used in an MS example, here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/228477  But that's all I got.